# Javascript - sort and manipulate array of dates

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to prep a table which would have a header be an array of months/year. So the table would look roughly like such:

```
          month1/year, month2/year, month3/year, etc....
field1:
field2:
field3:
```

The particular months/years are based upon a start and end date provided by a user. Based on some answers here, I have the logic working, however I hit a snag. By the way I've gone about getting the month (using getMonth()), it returns it as the index (so 0 for Jan, etc.). My first thought was just to +1, but clearly I then run into an issue with December -> January. My javascript skills are weak, so my only thought is to write in an if statement and adjust the final array after the fact.

Here's what I have so far:

```
function dateRange(startDate, endDate, steps = 1) {
   const dateArray = [];
   let currentDate = new Date(startDate);
      
   while (currentDate <= new Date(endDate)) {
   dateArray.push(new Date(currentDate));
   // Use UTC date to prevent problems with time zones and DST
   currentDate.setUTCDate(currentDate.getUTCDate() + steps);
   }
        
   console.log("dateArray: ", dateArray)

   const monthSet = dateArray.map(i => `${i.getMonth()}/${i.getFullYear()}`)
   const header = [...new Set(monthSet)]
   return header;
}
const dates = dateRange(isStart, isEnd);
console.log(dates);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking, sorry. But if you're wondering how to increment the month index without getting numbers like 13, 14, etc., you can use the modulo operator:

```
 1 % 12 ===  1;
 2 % 12 ===  2;
 3 % 12 ===  3;
10 % 12 === 10;
12 % 12 ===  0;
13 % 12 ===  1;
```

You should be safe simply adding `1` to `.getMonth()`, since that function will only ever yield values `0` though `11`.

Comment: Ah, I appreciate that, was overthinking and assumed incorrectly. Thanks